# iOS push notification won't fire application function

Tags: ios, function, logging, notifications, push

So my problem is that I want to log when the push notification service gets activated for my app. I know for that to happen this function gets called

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)_deviceToken
```

so I put my logging code in there. However the breakpoints basically state that the program never enters that function. I just recently added the logging code and the device im testing on already has that app activated for push notifications.

Therefore my question is, what can I do, I want to test if my logging code is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
```

This will go in your `AppDelegate.m`

Answer (score -2):

[- (void)unregisterForRemoteNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications)

Comment: ??? I don't think this is what he wants. He wants to know when the push notification is activated. Not unregister remote notifications

Comment: Read the question one more time.